# Android gallery and async loading

Tags: android, android-asynctask, gallery

I'm trying to load images with an async taks from internet. The problem is that the image will not update. Code:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView i ;
        i = new ImageView(this.mContext);
        AsycTask task =  new AsycTask();
        task.url = new URL(mImageIds.get(position));
        task.iv = i;
        task.execute(i);
    return i;
     }

     public class AsycTask extends AsyncTask<ImageView, Void, Bitmap>{
        public Bitmap bm2;
        public ImageView iv;
        public URL url;
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(ImageView... arg0) {
            iv = arg0[0];
            try {
                bm2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)url.getContent());

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return bm2;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
             // iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.sw10)
             iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.search);
             iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
             iv.setImageBitmap(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }
}
```

Why isn't the Image updating after I set the Bitmap?
I'm using an async task to update my Image, is this possible?

Comment: Have you put any logging in to find out what bits do and don't execute?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use UnivsersalImageLoader lib which will simplify your development.
Your code for image loading will be next:

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUrl, imageView); // Default options will be used
```

[UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: Nope The image is still empty

Comment: Is ImageView visible? Could you try to load image into static ImageView ?